# Displayed textual conditions

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, mathematics

Displayed equations in (AMS-)LaTeX is well documented and widely understood.  Sometimes, however, one wants to have displayed *textual* conditions in mathematical writings.  This is seen in the following image (from Hodges's *Model Theory*):[image]

Here (5.12) is a displayed formula that we all know well, whereas (5.13) is what I am trying to describe.  It appears that lines like (5.13) have different spacings than genuine displayed formulas like (5.12).

What is the standard mechanism in (AMS-)LaTeX to be used to display conditions like (5.13)?  Not only does a math environment solely containing `\text` seem idiotic, but also it violates the principle of semantic mark-ups: lines like (5.12) are just some prose displayed differently, not mathematical symbols (albeit the former may *contain* the latter).

Addendum: another opposition toward usual equation commands + `\text` is that they cannot handle line breaks automatically.  With genuine equations manual line breaks pose no issue (though cumbersome), but with prose the line breaks must look the same as elsewhere.

Comment: I would use `\text` here is it **is** for textual comments in displayed math. Note I would write it as `\text{$A$ is $I'$-injective ...}`

Comment: "a math environment solely containing \text seem idiotic" it seems natural and semantically valid to me. outer `equation` as it is a displayed thing numbered as an equation, then `\text` because it is text.

Comment: A multi-line text can be treated (and numbered) as an equation by setting it in a `\parbox`.  Small graphics can also be set in this manner.  When the textual context makes sense to do this, it is not inappropriate.